# How to swap the quarters of quadratic matrix clockwise (beginning from top left corner)?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, matrix

I want to write a program that:

1. Generates quadratic matrix of size (2Nx2N)
2. Prints this matrix
3. Swaps the quarters of the matrix clockwise (beginning from top
   left corner)
4. Prints changed matrix

For example, the output of my program should be like this:

```
01 02 03 04 
05 06 07 08 
09 10 11 12
13 14 15 16

Matrix (changed)

09 10 01 02
13 14 05 06
11 12 03 03 
15 16 07 08
```

Here is my source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const int n = 4; // size of matrix

void CreateMatrix(int matrix[][n], int n); // functions' prototypes
void PrintMatrix(int matrix[][n], int n);
void ProcessMatrix(int matrix[][n], int n);
int main()
{
    int matrix[n][n];

    srand(time(NULL));

    CreateMatrix(matrix, n);    //create matrix
    PrintMatrix(matrix, n);     //print matrix
    ProcessMatrix(matrix, n);   //change matrix

    cout<<"\nMatrix(changed):\n"; 

    PrintMatrix(matrix, n);    // print changed matrix

}
void CreateMatrix(int matrix[][n],int n)
{
    for (int i =0; i<n; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j<n; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = rand()%10;
}
void PrintMatrix(int matrix[][n], int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout<<matrix[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
}
void ProcessMatrix(int matrix[][n], int n) 
{
    // I don't know how to write this function
}
```

So my question is how to write ProcessMatrix function?
Any help is appreciated!
By the way, here is my attempt to do it:

```
void ProcessMatrix(int matrix[][n], int n) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i<n/2; i++) 
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n/2; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = matrix[i+n/4][j+n/4];        // something wrong here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It feels a bit like a homework. Did you try anything?

Comment: please give us the matrix you have and the matrix result you want.

Comment: first thing: use vectors or arrays it will make your code simpler as you don't need to propagate the size of the arrays

Comment: @Gabriel I would use vectors but I can't, because my teacher won't like it

Comment: your teacher does not know his job. The C++ Programming Language (3rd edition). 1997. ISBN: 0-201-88954-4. Chapter C.14.11 'Prefer vector over array'. This comes from the guy who invented C++ so cannot quote better

Comment: Note that, in your spec, the matrices are 2n by 2n, but in your code they are n by n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> // something wrong here

The thing that is wrong there is that you start overwriting some of parts of the matrix before processing them.

You need a copy of the matrix what you can work with, without modifying the original one. Once that's done you can update the original.

```
void ProcessMatrix(int matrix[][n], int n) {
    int newmatrix[n][n];

    // build new one
    for (int i = 0; i<n/2; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<n/2; j++) {
            newmatrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j+n/2];
            newmatrix[i][j+n/2] = matrix[i+n/2][j+n/2];
            newmatrix[i+n/2][j+n/2] = matrix[i+n/2][j];
            newmatrix[i+n/2][j] = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }

    // copy it to old
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = newmatrix[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To be honest, I was thinking about copy of the matrix, too. But my code didn't compile... Thank you very much! You helped me a lot!

Comment: You don't to copy the whole matrix; just one of the values in each rotation.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. I loop over one quadrant worth of elements and handling one element from each quadrant in all iteration thus processing all elements. At least that's the idea :) Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You rotate m[i][j], m[N+i][j], m[N+i][N+j], and m[N+i][j] for (i,j) in (0..N-1, 0..N-1).

Comment: I assume you mean that there are should be 4 for-loops. But what are the conditions of those loops? I don't get it.

Comment: Shouldn't the intervals be `(0..n/2-1)`?

Comment: Oh I think I know the source of confusion. The question talks about 2Nx2N matrix (which you used in the answer) but OP's code uses `n` as the actual size of the matrix and I used that in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the following is for `N` being half the size of the matrix, as used in the description of the question, but not in the code. The matrix here is `m[2 * N][2 * N]`.

The idea is that you iterate over one quarter of the matrix, and then do a cyclical swap of the 4 elements at the corresponding positions in all 4 quarters. The elements need to move in a cycle shown here:

```
m[i    ][k] ----> m[i    ][N + k]
     A                  |
     |                  |
     |                  |
     |                  V
m[N + i][k] <---- m[N + i][N + k]
```

You only need one temporary variable for this cyclical swap. The core part of the code looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    for (int k = 0; k < N; ++k) {
        int t = m[i][k];
        m[i][k] = m[N + i][k];
        m[N + i][k] = m[N + i][N + k];
        m[N + i][N + k] = m[i][N + k];
        m[i][N + k] = t;
    }
}
```